# Import decision tree from R into Orange

Tags: orange

I have a decision tree made with rpart in R. Is there a way to bring this tree into orange to view and interact with? I would like to use the classification tree viewer in Orange as it more interactive.

Cheers

Comment: You can't. Why don't you construct a tree with Orange, too?

Comment: My dataset is huge and it took a while to get the tree the way I wanted in R. Orange struggles with the amount of data input into the tree. Cheers